# ZeroMQ vs Twisted vs Autobahn

Tags: python, twisted, zeromq, autobahn

ZeroMQ is a socket communication library used in Python.

But what are Twisted and Autobahn? Why would we need to use them if ZeroMQ already exists? What is the difference between Twisted and Autobahn?

Answer (score 2):

- Twisted "is an event-driven networking engine" (take from their Web site) and used as the basis for networking software.
- Autobahn|Python as a WebSocket library provides a WebSocket implementation for Python

It is only when looking at Autobahn|Python as a [WAMP](http://wamp-proto.org/) library that you can really compare something here to ZeroMQ.

I'll leave the comparison to others, since I'm involved in the Autobahn projects and thus biased. Generally speaking: Just because one library/framework provides a solution in a problem space, this does not mean that there is no place for other solutions in that space.